# When are my post requests being fired based on woocomerce events, and how do I console my php code so I can debug

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks

I posted this code before it has been passed on to me, but this time I have a different question. We are using an integration with a company called GiveX who has given me very little documentation. The company that hired me had to sign a nda, so I don't think I can reveal much of the documentation they have revealed to us. I will try and make it as clear as possible what I am trying to achieve. I will place all my code below my questions with titles of the file naming in Wordpress.

1. **How do I console log for example the `$result` of the `gi_check_balance()` function in the `integrate.php` file?** what I want to know is what giveX is sending back to us. Now this is even if this function is sending a `post` request to giveX I can't even tell. **And where am I supposed to be to see this consoled? on the order complete page? or in some logs somewhere?**
2. **What does `add_action( 'wp_ajax_gi_check_balance', 'gi_check_balance' );` this line do**? I see that in the Wordpress docs `add_action` is a hook that fires at a certain point and the first value should be a `string` and the second a function, I see that to be true however what is the point of creating this hook, I don't see the first value the string referenced anywhere else, so how is it triggered? or when is that function run or does just giving it a `string` name and a function allow that function to run?
3. Again there are two functions `gi_check_balance()` and `gi_secure_register()` **how do I know when these are fired?** how do these functions connect to the `check-balance.js` file and the `secure-register.js`file (now my understanding of the `gi_secure_register()` function is that it is only for testing purposes, the only difference I know is the code that is sent in the post request labeled as the `method` one is `904` and one is `994` and they are supposed to do different things but reading through giveX documentation I can't really tell the difference.
4. Now I am aware that there is a webhook as well, and it seems to run based on a custom topic in woocommerce that is defined inside the `integrate.php` file. This web hook also seems to make a post request to giveX url, now I can't for the life of me understand why would we be firing a post request 3 times, one in the `integrate.php` plugin file itself, one in the `webhook.php` file and another in either one of the `js` files. I know it will be hard for someone to determine this for me, but if I could know **what scenarios in a woocommerce completed order these post requests will be fired?** it will help me understand why there are three different ones.
5. This section of the email that is being sent by the webhook `<b>Card Number:</b> ' . $response->result[3] . '<br /> <b>PIN:</b> ' . $response_reference[1] . '<br /> <b>Card Amount:</b> ' . $response->result[4] . '<br /> <b>Reference Number:</b> ' . $response_reference[0] . '</p>'` currently returns empty variables in the email. **I want to figure out why giveX is not sending back data?** I'd like to be able to console log this result somewhere I can see any errors coming back from giveX.
6. So Basically, I would like some help breaking down when certain functions are being fired based off of events in woocommerce/wordpress. Also I want to know which `post` requests are actually being fired, because I would think we only have to send one request to giveX to order these gift card purchase.

Ok Here is the code (thanks so much ahead of time :)

`plugins/givex/integrate.php`

```
 // Get grouped product ID from child product ID
 function get_parent_grouped_id( $children_id ){
     global $wpdb;
     $results = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT post_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta
         WHERE meta_key = '_children' AND meta_value LIKE '%$children_id%'");
     // Will only return one product Id or false if there is zero or many
     return sizeof($results) == 1 ? reset($results) : false;
 }
 /**
  * add_new_topic_hooks will add a new webhook topic hook. 
  * @param array $topic_hooks Esxisting topic hooks.
  */
 function add_new_topic_hooks( $topic_hooks ) {
    // Array that has the topic as resource.event with arrays of actions that call that topic.
    $new_hooks = array(
        'order.gift_card' => array(
            'order_gift_card_filter',
            ),
        );
    return array_merge( $topic_hooks, $new_hooks );
 }
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_webhook_topic_hooks', 'add_new_topic_hooks' );
 /**
  * add_new_topic_events will add new events for topic resources.
  * @param array $topic_events Existing valid events for resources.
  */
 function add_new_topic_events( $topic_events ) {
    // New events to be used for resources.
    $new_events = array(
        'gift_card',
        );
    return array_merge( $topic_events, $new_events );
 }
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_valid_webhook_events', 'add_new_topic_events' );
 /**
  * add_new_webhook_topics adds the new webhook to the dropdown list on the Webhook page.
  * @param array $topics Array of topics with the i18n proper name.
  */
 function add_new_webhook_topics( $topics ) {
    // New topic array to add to the list, must match hooks being created.
    $new_topics = array( 
        'order.gift_card' => __( 'Order Gift Card', 'woocommerce' ),
        );
    return array_merge( $topics, $new_topics );
 }
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_webhook_topics', 'add_new_webhook_topics' );
 /**
  * my_order_item_check will check an order when it is created through the checkout form,
  * if it has product ID 1030 as one of the items, it will fire off the action `order_gift_card_filter`
  * 
  * @param  int    $order_id    The ID of the order that was just created.
  * @param  array  $posted_data Array of all of the data that was posted through checkout form.
  * @param  object $order       The order object.
  * @return null
  */
  function my_order_item_check( $order_id, $posted_data, $order ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order_status = $order->status;
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {

        if ( is_a( $item, 'WC_Order_Item_Product' ) ) {

            if ( 1457 === $item->get_product_id() ) {

          $item_data = $item->get_data();
          $item_meta_data_group = $item_data['meta_data'];
          $gift_card_data = array();
          foreach ( $item_meta_data_group as $item_meta_data ) {
            $gift_card_data[$item_meta_data->key] = $item_meta_data->value;
          }

          do_action( 'order_gift_card_filter', $order_id, $posted_data, $order );

            }
        }
    }
  }

//The two below actions are what the order.created webhook is tied into, it is up to you to use these if you wish. 

//add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'my_order_item_check', 10, 4 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'my_order_item_check', 10, 3 );
//add_action( 'woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'my_order_item_check', 10, 2 );

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_ajax_script' );
function add_ajax_script() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'check-balance', plugins_url( '/check-balance.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'secure-register', plugins_url( '/secure-register.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
  wp_localize_script( 'check-balance', 'gi_check_balance', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ) );
  wp_localize_script( 'secure-register', 'gi_secure_register', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_gi_check_balance', 'gi_check_balance' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_gi_check_balance', 'gi_check_balance' );
function gi_check_balance() {
  $gx_url_1 = 'https://givexurl-1.com';
  $gx_url_2 = 'https://givexurl-2.com';
  $gx_port_1 = port;
  $gx_port_2 = port;
  $gx_post_url_1 = $gx_url_1 . ':' . $gx_port_1;
  $gx_post_url_2 = $gx_url_2 . ':' . $gx_port_2;
  $gx_user = 'user';
  $gx_password = 'pass';

  $gx_card_number = $_POST['gx_card_number'];

  $data = array(
    'method' => '994',
    'params' => [
      'en',
      'rc1',
      //null,
      $gx_user,
      $gx_password,
      $gx_card_number,
      $gx_card_pin,
      null
    ],
    'id' => 'test'
  );

  $options = array(
    'http' => array(
      'method' => 'POST',
      'header' => 'Content-Type: application/json',
      'content' => json_encode( $data )
    )
  );

  $context  = stream_context_create( $options );
  $result = file_get_contents( $gx_post_url_1, false, $context );
  if ( $result == false ) {
    $result = file_get_contents( $gx_post_url_2, false, $context );
  }
  $response = json_decode( $result );

  echo $result;
  //echo json_encode($result) ;
  //var_dump( $response );
  //echo $response;

  die();
}

// function only for dev testing purposes
//add_action( 'wp_ajax_gi_secure_register', 'gi_secure_register' );
function gi_secure_register() {
  $gx_url_1 = 'https://givexurl-1.com';
  $gx_url_2 = 'https://givexurl-2.com';
  $gx_port_1 = port;
  $gx_port_2 = port;
  $gx_post_url_1 = $gx_url_1 . ':' . $gx_port_1;
  $gx_post_url_2 = $gx_url_2 . ':' . $gx_port_2;
  $gx_user = 'user';
  $gx_password = 'pass';

  $gx_register_amount = $_POST['gx_register_amount'];

  $data = array(
    'method' => '904',
    'params' => [
      'en',
      'rc2',
      //null,
      $gx_user,
      $gx_password,
      $gx_register_amount,
      null,
      null,
      null
    ],
    'id' => 'test'
  );

  $options = array(
    'http' => array(
      'method' => 'POST',
      'header' => 'Content-Type: application/json',
      'content' => json_encode( $data )
    )
  );

  $context  = stream_context_create( $options );
  $result = file_get_contents( $gx_post_url_1, false, $context );
  if ( $result == false ) {
    $result = file_get_contents( $gx_post_url_2, false, $context );
  }
  $response = json_decode( $result );

  echo json_encode($result);

  die();
}
```

`plugins/givex/webhook.php`

```
<?php 
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$passed = false;
$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$secret = 'P&_(e>P _I?%/aOW?wv0H.U149+Eyv8bh~qXd<6XrIY8+K0oo]';
$sig = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $request_body, $secret, true));

if( !function_exists('apache_request_headers') ) {
  function apache_request_headers() {
    $headers = array();
    foreach($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
        if (substr($key, 0, 5) <> 'HTTP_') {
            continue;
        }
        $header = str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', strtolower(substr($key, 5)))));
        $headers[$header] = $value;
    }
    return $headers;
  }
}
$header = apache_request_headers(); 
foreach ( $header as $headers => $value ) {
  if( $headers == 'X-Wc-Webhook-Signature' ) {
    if ( $value == $sig ) {
      $passed = true;
    }
  }
}

if( $passed !== true ) {
  header("Location: https://our-url.com");
} else {

$gx_url_1 = 'https://givexurl-1.com';
$gx_url_2 = 'https://givexurl-2.com';
$gx_port_1 = port;
$gx_port_2 = port;
$gx_post_url_1 = $gx_url_1 . ':' . $gx_port_1;
$gx_post_url_2 = $gx_url_2 . ':' . $gx_port_2;
$gx_user = 'user';
$gx_password = 'pass';

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

foreach( $data['line_items'] as $item ) {
  if( $item['product_id'] == 1457 ) {
    $item_meta_data_group = $item['meta_data'];
    $gift_card_data = array();
    foreach( $item_meta_data_group as $item_meta_data ) {
      $gift_card_data[$item_meta_data['key']] = $item_meta_data['value'];
    }

    $data_modified = array(
      'method' => '904',
      'params' => [
        'en',
        null,
        $gx_user,
        $gx_password,
        str_replace(array(',', '$', ' '), '', $gift_card_data['gift-card-amount']),
        null,
        null,
        null
      ],
      'id' => 'test'
    );

    $options = array(
      'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-Type: application/json',
        'content' => json_encode( $data_modified )
      )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create( $options );
    //$result = file_get_contents( $gx_post_url, false, $context );
    $result = file_get_contents( $gx_post_url_1, false, $context );
    if ( $result == false ) {
      $result = file_get_contents( $gx_post_url_2, false, $context );
    }
    $response = json_decode( $result );
    $response_reference = explode(':', $response->result[2]);
    echo $result;

    $to = $gift_card_data['recipient_email'];
    $subject_decoded = 'You received a gift card ';
    $subject = '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode( $subject_decoded ) . '?=';
    $subject1 = 'test';
    $message = '<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;"><tbody><tr><td style="padding: 40px 40px 20px; background-color: #f9f9f9;" align="center"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse;"><tbody>';
    $message .= '<tr><td align="center" valign="bottom" style="padding: 0 0 20px;">';
    $message .= '</td></tr>';
    $message .= '<tr><td align="center" style="padding: 10px 40px 20px; background-color: #ffffff; color: #676767; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">';
    $message .= '<h2 style="font-family: Garamond, serif; font-size: 28px; font-weight: 600; color: #444444;">' . (!empty($gift_card_data['recipient_name']) ? $gift_card_data['recipient_name'] : 'Whoa') . ', you&rsquo;ve got ' . $gift_card_data['gift-card-amount'] . ' to spend at!</h2>';
    $message .= '<p style="color: #676767;">' . (!empty($gift_card_data['sender']) ? $gift_card_data['sender'] : 'Someone') . ' sent you a gift card' . (!empty($gift_card_data['message']) ? ' with the following message:' : '.') . '</p>';
    if( !empty($gift_card_data['message']) ) {
      $message .= '<p style="color: #676767;"><i><br />' . nl2br($gift_card_data['message']) . '<br /><br /></i></p>';
    }
    //$message .= '<img src="https://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=' . $response->result[3] . '&style=68&type=C39&width=300&height=50&xres=1&font=4" alt="" />';
    // barcode generator website: https://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/index.php
    $message .= '<p style="color: 676767; font-size: 1.25em;"><b>Card Number:</b> ' . $response->result[3] . '<br /> <b>PIN:</b> ' . $response_reference[1] . '<br /> <b>Card Amount:</b> ' . $response->result[4] . '<br /> <b>Reference Number:</b> ' . $response_reference[0] . '</p>';
    $message .= '</td></tr>';
    $message .= '<tr><td align="center" style="padding: 20px 0 0;">';
    $message .= '<p style="color: #676767;"><b>We look forward to you dining with us!</b></p>';  
    $message .= '</td></tr>';
    $message .= '</tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table>';
    $headers = "From: Gift Cards <test.com>\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: noreply@test.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  }
} // end foreach

} // end if else '$passed !== true'
```

`plugins/givex/check-balance.js`

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      // checks card balance
      $('.gi-check-balance').submit(function() {

        var gx_card_number = $(this).find('[name=card-number]').val()
        var gx_card_pin = $(this).find('[name=card-pin]').val()

        $.ajax({
          url: gi_check_balance.ajax_url,
          type: 'post',
          data: {
            action: 'gi_check_balance',
            gx_card_number: gx_card_number,
            gx_card_pin: gx_card_pin
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(response) {
            console.log(response)
            $('.gi-check-balance-result').text(response['result'][2])
            //$('.gi-check-balance-result').text(JSON.stringify(response))
            $('.gi-check-balance-result').show()
          }
        })

        return false

      })

    })
```

`plugins/givex/secure-register.js`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // registers gift card
  $('.gi-secure-register').submit(function() {

    var gx_register_amount = $(this).find('[name=register-amount]').val()

    $.ajax({
      url: gi_secure_register.ajax_url,
      type: 'post',
      data: {
        action: 'gi_secure_register',
        gx_register_amount: gx_register_amount
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
        //$('.gi-secure-register-result').html('Reference Number: ' + response['result'][2] + '<br>' + 'Card Number: ' + response['result'][3] + '<br>' + 'Card Amount: ' + response['result'][4])
        $('.gi-secure-register-result').text(response)
        $('.gi-secure-register-result').show();
        console.log(response);
      }
    })

    return false

  })

})
```

UPDATE

> First Noticed error. It looks like since I am on localhost I am
>   getting rejected from the https connection? Now I know very little
>   about ssl, how would I get that working locally. Do I need something
>   further from the url I am sending the request too?

```
[22-Nov-2019 02:59:00 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in /Users/anderskitson/Local Sites/river-cafe/app/public/wp-content/plugins/givex-integrate/webhook.dev.php on line 94
```

The error above is solved here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58924492/2949184 and solves the main issues I have been having.

Comment: there is too much questions for my little comment, I just answer one : the hooks starting by `wp_ajax_nopriv_` and `wp_ajax_` are fired by `admin-ajax.php` : https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: ok, is there a way to know what even on the user side would be causing admin-ajax.php to run?

Comment: search for `gi_secure_register` in JavaScript file to find ajax calls.

Comment: Sometimes its a good idea to just add some error_log statements to what is being fired and then do a bunch of user cases (click around in woocommerce) to see when they fire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. When it comes to console logging, I use `error_log();` and then look in the PHP error log file.
   See https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/php-logging-basics/
2. When I want to know where a hook is used, i take the first string, `'wp_ajax_gi_check_balance'` and search the entire website (or less if I know where to look) in *.php files and look for a line that says `do_action('wp_ajax_gi_check_balance'...`.

I'll post more later.

**Update**

I realize I'm not much more savvy on the rest of your questions than you are. I think at least the error logging can get you much further in uncovering of how it works. And I'm off to bed, but I may check again tomorrow in case you have any updates.

**Update 2**

About your SSL error: [file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1, Failed to enable crypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-failed-to-enable-crypto)

Did you try googling the error yourself?

Comment: your error_log(); solution already helped me a bunch, and don't want to bog anyone down with all the questions for now. Thanks